# Populate select box within the edit page of an entity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I've created a asp.net MVC application which uses the entity framework for "fun".

I have two entities, one for users and one for faculty (school). Each user has one faculty which needs to be able to change. I'd like to do this using a select box with the name of each faculty displayed. The final HTML should look something like this:

```
<select>
    <option>Faculty name 1</option>
    <option>Faculty name 2</option>
    <option>Faculty name 3</option>
<select>
```

The below code currently displays the id value of the faculty in a text box with type number. This Id is part of the user entity and not currently taken from the faculty entity.

I'm unsure of how to

- Pass the list of faculties into the HTML for display
- Store the selected faculty in the user entity faculty variable

**Edit.cshtml**

```
@model Purely_Servers.Models.user

<div class="form-group col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.school, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.school, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

**usersController**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Purely_Servers.DAL;
using Purely_Servers.Models;

namespace Purely_Servers.Controllers
{
    public class usersController : Controller
    {
        private serverContext db = new serverContext();

        // GET: users
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.Users.ToList());
        }

        // GET: users/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }

            user user = db.Users.Find(id);

            if (user == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(user);
        }

        // GET: users/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: users/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "id,first_name,last_name,email,house_number,street,city,postcode,authorised,school,archived")] user user)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Users.Add(user);

                // find the users school in the database, add the user to the faculty's collection
                var faculty = db.Faculties.Find(user.school);
                user.faculty = faculty;

                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(user);
        }

        // GET: users/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            user user = db.Users.Find(id);
            if (user == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(user);
        }

        // POST: users/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "id,first_name,last_name,email,house_number,street,city,postcode,authorised,school,archived")] user user)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // find the users school in the database, add the user to the faculty's collection
                var faculty = db.Faculties.Find(user.school); // get the value from the page
                user.faculty = faculty;


                db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(user);
        }

        // GET: users/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            user user = db.Users.Find(id);
            if (user == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(user);
        }

        // POST: users/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            user user = db.Users.Find(id);
            db.Users.Remove(user);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

**Users model**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Purely_Servers.Models
{
    [Table("userTable")]
    public class user
    {
        [Key]
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string first_name { get; set; }
        public string last_name { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public int house_number { get; set; }
        public string street { get; set; }
        public string city { get; set; }
        public string postcode { get; set; }
        public int authorised { get; set; }
        public int school { get; set; }
        public int archived { get; set; }

        public virtual faculty faculty { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Any help much appreciated

Comment: This is how you create a selectlist & pass it to the View:[http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/03/11/dropdownlistfor-with-asp-net-mvc.aspx](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/03/11/dropdownlistfor-with-asp-net-mvc.aspx)

Comment: To store the faculty against a user, you need to add a `FacultyId` property to the `User` class. This should be updated with the value from the selectlist when you submit the form.

Comment: int school is the facultyID from the user model. It is this that is currently being updated.

Comment: @markpsmith If I understand that link you posted, I need to have the select list created within the faculty entity?

Comment: Kind of - the link demonstrates creating the selectlist in a Model. It looks like you're not using models - you will need to. I'll add an answer because it's impossible to write code in these comment boxes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main change is that you need to pass a Model to your View, not just the `User` entity.

Create a Model:

```
public class EditUserModel
{
    public user User{get; set;}
    public SelectList FacultyList{get; set;}
}
```

Controller Edit method:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
    var model = new EditUserModel
        {
          User = db.Users.Find(id),
          FacultyList = (from f in db.Faculties
                        select new SelectListItem
                        {
                            Value = f.Id.ToString(),
                            Text = f.Name
                        }).ToList();
        };
     return View(model);
}
```

View:

```
@model EditUserModel

<div>
    <div >
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.User.school, Model.FacultyList )

    </div>
</div>
```

There are lots of improvements to be made but this is a step in the right direction.

Comment: Fantastic. It was the concept I was struggling to get my head around. I'll have a play and get back to you.

Comment: This works perfect with the FacultyList being a List<SelectListItem> within the EditUserModel. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you want to improve this further, you could look into amending the model so it only includes the User properties that you need for display and update instead of the whole entity.